# 68000 - TRAP 14 on 68000 and TRAP 15 on EASy68K

Tags: 68000, easy68k

Are these the same? Is TRAP 15 on the EASy68K the same as TRAP 14 on the 68000 board. Ive tried looking for this answer and am under the notion that it is right but i would like to make sure.

Could somone please confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "the same"?

The instruction is `TRAP`, it takes a 4-bit immediate vector index that controls which handler is invoked.

So of course the two instructions `TRAP #14` and `TRAP #15` are not the same.

The handlers can of course be the same, causing the two instructions to have the same result, but that's impossible to answer since you don't specify all your software.